# Wordpress: Edit HTML if shortcode is found

Tags: wordpress

I need to remove a shortcode in the_content() and insert it into another html structure.

E.g., if the post is

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is the content [shortcode id="50"]</p>
```

I need to render as

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is the content</p>

<div class="new-div">
[shortcode id="50"]
</div>
```

This it the code inside functions.php in theme.

It's remove all the content, not only the shortcode.

```
function gallery_exists() {

    global $post;

    $content = $post->post_content;

    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery') ) {

        $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

        if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $content, $matches ) ) {

            function remove_gallery() {

                $gallery = $matches[0][0];

                $content = strip_shortcodes($content,$gallery);
                $content = unescape_invalid_shortcodes( $content );

                return $content;

            }

            add_filter('the_content', 'remove_gallery');


        }



    }
}

add_action('wp','gallery_exists');
```

Comment: Why are you using `$matches[0][0]`?

Comment: Because in $mathes[0][0] there is exatcly the shortcode that I need, with optional parameter (found via a var_dump($matches) )